# HTML JS <base> exceptions / <base> recreation in JS

Tags: javascript, html

My goal here is that I am making a web proxy, and for rewriting HTML, I will need a `<base>` for the assets to fetch off. The problem is that I can't find anyway to have exceptions for `<base>` which I need for srcs and hrefs beginning with `./` or not `/` . If its not possible to do this with `<base>`, then is there Javascript that works and behaves exactly like `<base>`. I would also need to create another `<base>` for srcs and hrefs that start with `./` or don't start with `/`

If I am not being clear enough then please explain in comments. I am not sure what code to put here since I am talking about a tag.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't find anyway to have exceptions for  which I need for srcs and hrefs beginning with ./ or not / .

Why you can't use `./` or `/` ? You are absolutely allowed to use.

See the note on [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base#attr-href) about `href` attribute:

> The base URL to be used throughout the document for relative URLs. Absolute and relative URLs are allowed.

For further details, you may be interested to look into [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10202682/2138752) about absolute and relative links.